# Device owner mode かどうか知る方法

Tags: android

端末がDevice owner modeで動作しているかどうか、アプリケーションから知る方法はありますか。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。
下のサンプルコードをアプリに実装することでアプリからdeviceownerか否かを判定することができます。
DevicePolicyManagerのインスタンスを以下のように作成し、isDeviceOwnerApp関数で
デバイスオーナーかどうかを判定します。
以下がサンプルコードです。

```
//import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
//import android.widget.Toast;

DevicePolicyManager manager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

if (!manager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()))
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"device owner が設定されていません", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```